# How to access the HTML table from PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a page with a java script that adds a row to a table. On the same page there is a PHP script that should read the table and add it to the database. How do I read the table using PHP ?

Comment: Post your code that you have or share us with www.jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're thinking of will not *directly* work.

A Javascript script is executed on the client side only, whereas a PHP is executed on the server side only, and before the datas are sent to the client.

PHP can not *directly* read the table.

What you can do is use AJAX to send the data from the user's browser to a PHP script that'll use them.

You'll find more infos [here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/%E2%80%8E).

Answer (score 0):

PHP is serverside programing, the PHP code serves data to the client - PHP can't read from the client.

If you add a row using javascript, PHP has no way of getting that info.

You'll need to use Ajax to solve your specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "read the table" with PHP. You will have to send the data of the table to the server (and read it with PHP) using JavaScript or CGI.

A well-known technique to do this is called [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).